# Get IOBluetoothDevice * from CBPeripheral * (Mac OS X)

Tags: bluetooth, core-bluetooth, iobluetooth

I am wondering if there is a way i can get an `IOBluetoothDevice *` object from a `CBPeripheral *` object because I am making an advanced bluetooth controller framework (Its going to be based on `IOBluetooth`) and Im using it so scan for `Bluetooth Classic` and `Bluetooth Low Energy` devices. Here are some of the problems:

1. `IOBluetooth` does allow you to search for both networks but for some reason its not showing up all of the `Bluetooth Low Energy` Devices that `CoreBluetooth` is.
2. If I use `CoreBluetooth` to search for `Bluetooth Low Energy` Devices I won't be able to get the address which I require for later use.

So is there any way i can get an `IOBluetoothDevice` object from a `CBPeripheral`?

thanks :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out that I can search through `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.bluetooth.plist > CoreBluetoothCache` which just happens to contain the UUID and in its dictionary `DeviceAddress` = the address ;).

so I can get the UUID of a `CBPeripheral` by using the method

```
NSString *uuid = [[<*CBPeripheral*> identifier] UUIDString];
```

and then looking it up in the property list

```
NSDicionary *btdict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"/Library/Preferences/com.apple.bluetooth.plist"];
NSDictionary *bleDevices = [btDict objectForKey:@"CoreBluetoothCache"];
NSString *address = [[bleDevices objectForKey:uuid] objectForKey:@"DeviceAddress"];
```

Then create a new IOBluetoothDevice with that address:

```
IOBluetoothDevice *device = [IOBluetoothDevice deviceWithAddressString:address];
```

Its as easy as that :D

Answer (score 1):

Swift 5.3 solution:

```
fileprivate func getDeviceAddress(for cbPeripheral: CBPeripheral) -> String?
{
    if let userDefaults = UserDefaults(suiteName: "/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Bluetooth")
   {
        if  let coreBluetoothCache = userDefaults.object(forKey: "CoreBluetoothCache") as? [String : Any]
        {
            if let deviceData = coreBluetoothCache[cbPeripheral.identifier.uuidString] as? [String : Any]
            {
                return deviceData["DeviceAddress"] as? String
            }
        }
    }
        
    return nil
}
```

Usage:

```
if let deviceAddress = self.getDeviceAddress(for: peripheral)
{
    if let bluetoothDevice = IOBluetoothDevice(addressString: deviceAddress)
    {
        // Do your stuff
    }
}
```